# while deleting a file i am getting error 

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
>   System.IO.File.Delete(String path)
>   at
>   secure.course.ContentList.ListCourses.imgBtnExport_Click(Object
>   sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in
>   secure\course\ContentList\ListCourses.aspx.cs:line
>   1639

above is the stack trace for the error which i am getting while Deleting a Zip file.

Comment: Is there an error message at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The process cannot access the file 'content\temp\Courses\MSOf­ficeExcel2007MSOE2007.Zip' because it is being used by another process

Well, it sounds like MSOfficeExcel2007MSOE2007.zip file is in use and cannot be accessed.  If you are accessing it in your code, you'll want to close it before you try to delete it.  If you aren't accessing it in your code, make sure you don't have another program with it open (IE - you checked the contents of the .zip file in WinZip and didn't close it)

Comment: i didn't think so i just export this file and after that when i saved t his file i am going to create another file on that directory and when i tried to deletee this file this error is coming

Comment: Something else is using the file.  That something else may possibly be you if you create the file.  Don't assume that nothing has the file in use, because as the error message indicates, that is not the case.  Close any other application that ever touches the file, check your application to see if you use the file prior to deleting it, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `Full control` permission on that folder.

```
Properties ---> Security
```